# npm пакет на чистом jsx для reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm

Я новичек.
Возможно ли и как создать npm пакет с чистым jsx, без предварительной сборки webpack`ом?
В пакете будут храниться ui компоненты для использования только в reactjs.
Идея в том, чтобы все подключенные из пакета компоненты собирались как локальные компоненты проекта с настройками для webpack из текущего проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не сможете пользоваться JSX без Babel.
Но вы можете использовать и JSX и Babel без сборки с помощью webpack. В таком случае увеличится нагрузка на клиента, так как Babel будет преобразовывать код каждый раз при загрузке страницы. Грубо говоря Webpack вам позволяет преобразовать один раз и отдает уже преобразованый код.

Comment: babel использоваться будет при сборке всего проекта, я же хочу вынести только общие для нескольких проектов компоненты. А параметры webpack у проектов должны быть разные.  Мне удается собрать сам пакет с компонентами, теперь задача заставить webpack проекта запускать babel для компонент из пакета, как будто это jsx локальных компонент проекта.